# SailsJS populate html table with each

Tags: jquery, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I cant retrieve model data to a html select tag. Heres my code so far.

```
% _.each(users, function(user){ %>
<select data-id="<%= user.id %>" data-model="user">
<option value="<%= user.id%>"><%= user.name %></option>
<% }) %>
```

I get an error when trying to lift the server, maybe it happen because im making a syntax mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of issues here, depending what you are trying to do. You are creating a different `<select>` element for each user (each having only a single `<option>`. What you probably want is a single `<select>` with multiple `<option>` tags:

```
<select id="userid" name="userid" data-model="user">
    <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
        <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.name %></option>
    <% }); %>
</select>
```

A couple of other sources of error are corrected: the initial templating tag is not missing its angle bracket, and the `<select>` has been given a `name` property (in case you are submitting this as part of a form), and an `id` property (in case you are getting the value using javascript).

If you are submitting this with a form, then a `userid` property will be included with the value being the value of the selected `<option>`.